# Python - Passing contents of list existing as dictionary value to a function that accepts multiple arguments?

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

New to programming, still getting the hang of Python.I am trying to pass the contents of a list which exists as a dictionary value, to a function that accepts multiple arguments. I have tried:

```
dict = {'1':['option1', 'option2', 'option3']}  

def print_list(param1, param2, param3):
    print param1
    print param2
    print param3

print_list(dict['1'])
```

However, I recieve the error:

```
TypeError: print_list() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

After some fiddling I understand why it doesn't work but short of trying to figure out a way to assign each list item to it's own variable, and then passing the variables to the function I am unsure how to solve this problem. I am working on a choose-your-own-adventure project that compares user input to the dictionary key, and passes the associated values (which are in a list) as arguments to the function producing the new scenario. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Read the bleeping tutorial.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
print_list(*dict['1'])
```